# How do you keep a GLKView (or UIView) in portrait mode regardles of the device orientation?

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0

I have seen this asked several times here on SO but none match exactly what I am looking for.

All I want to do is keep a single GLKView in portrait mode (stop the auto-rotate methods from the device to rotate this single view).

The catch is that I want everything else to be handled by the auto-rotate functions.

Since GLKView is a descendant of UIView I could just apply a transform to always keep putting it back to its original orientation performing the opposite rotation that the device is doing.

THIS however wont work because I cannot apply transforms directly to a layer because OpenGL will give me an error. "Failed to make complete framebuffer object 8cd6" (Maybe I have to rebuild my framebuffer object after the rotation or something?)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the best handling of rotation would be 
- pause your framebuffer rendering, get a snaphot of it during rotation animation
- unpause it after rotation.

Another way would be to use a container ViewController : setting your GLKView as only view of a ViewController child which would not rotate - as `UIViewController` provides the APIs for rotation